# Git gc or prune concurrent with receive

Tags: git

There are two hosts A and B.

A serves Git and receives revs pushed from B.

B only pushes and never receives, unless pulling by itself.

One can set B to GC or prune revs because there is no fear of concurrent operations, however can B push revs to A while A is GCing or pruning? What happens?

**I basically want to know if I am to tear down A's comms when running GCs or prunes, or there is no need for that.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git GC's [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) state:

> If git gc runs concurrently with another process, there is a risk of it deleting an object that the other process is using but hasn’t created a reference to. This may just cause the other process to fail or may corrupt the repository if the other process later adds a reference to the deleted object. Git has two features that significantly mitigate this problem:
>
> 1. Any object with modification time newer than the --prune date is kept, along with everything reachable from it.
> 2. Most operations that add an object to the database update the modification time of the object if it is already present so that #1 applies.
>
> However, these features fall short of a complete solution, so users who run commands concurrently have to live with some risk of corruption (which seems to be low in practice).

And further:

> `--prune=<date>`
>
> Prune loose objects older than date (default is 2 weeks ago, overridable by the config variable gc.pruneExpire). `--prune=now` prunes loose objects regardless of their age and increases the risk of corruption if another process is writing to the repository concurrently; see "NOTES" below. --prune is on by default.

So yes, there is a risk. However, if the clocks of A and B are fairly in sync and the Git commands you apply to the repository do not take longer than two weeks to complete, I would consider the risk of concurrent pushing to and GC'ing the same repository as being acceptable.